# Is there a name for what type of machine learning model I am using?

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently writing down a report on the inference benchmarks I have done.

Within these benchmarks I used YoloV3-Tiny in various *forms*, such as TensorFlow, TFLite, TFLite 8-bit quantized, TF-TRT 8-bit quantized, Edge TPU 8-bit quantized model.

I know that these are all basically in two formats (.pb and .tflite), but I was wondering if there was a general term applicable to this.

Is it model type, variant, format, version?

Basically I would like to say:
YoloV3-Tiny was used within this work in various _____ to show how different model _____ impact the inference time.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is simply "framework" and potentially "quantisation" or "backend", depending on how much do you want to go in detail with your description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am not happy with the term "framework" though, as it loses the distinction between the 5 different models I have used, condensing it down to just TensorFlow and TFLite.
I suppose backend fits the bill then?